# Problem in building RVIZ tutorial (Markers: Sending Basic Shapes)

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there. I am a beginner in ROS.

I am trying to go through the first tutorial of RVIZ which is sending basic shape. The page is [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes).

I followed exactly the tutorial with my build package in the path user/catkin_ws/src.
I added the file"basic_shapes.cpp"  and put it under src folder.
I also edited CMAKE file with the two lines from the tutorial page.

```
add_executable(basic_shapes src/basic_shapes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(basic_shapes ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

When I run "catkin_make", this error shows in the console.

```
user:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/home/user/simulation_ws/devel;/home/simulations/public_sim_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/home/user/simulation_ws/devel;/home/simulations/public_sim_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/user/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will bebuilt
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/local/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - using_markers
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'using_markers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(using_markers)
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at using_markers/CMakeLists.txt:207 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    src/basic_shapes.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: basic_shapes
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "basic_shapes".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Makefile:682: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

----------
```

update:
after running the code second time, the error below occurs:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/build'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:437: recipe for target 'using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

the content of CMAKE file is as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(using_markers)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  visualization_msgs
)
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES using_markers
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp visualization_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/using_markers.cpp
# )

add_executable(basic_shapes src/basic_shapes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(basic_shapes ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351599/problem-in-building-rviz-tutorial-(markers:-sending-basic-shapes)/) by [sole_unizon](https://answers.ros.org/users/54480/sole_unizon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-06**:
What is the output of: `ls -al /home/user/catkin_ws/src/using_markers/src/basic_shapes.cpp`?

**Comment by [sole_unizon](https://answers.ros.org/users/54480/sole_unizon/) on 2020-05-06**:
this is the console output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 4805 May  6 13:53 /home/user/catkin_ws/src/using_markers/src/basic_shapes.cpp
```

I also tried running the "catkin_make" command again and now the console shows this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/build'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:437: recipe for target 'using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

any idea of what's going on?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-06**:
Please show your `CMakeLists.txt`. Be sure to remove all the boilerplate comments in it. We don't need those.

And add your `CMakeLists.txt` to the question body. Do not post it here in a comment.

**Comment by [sole_unizon](https://answers.ros.org/users/54480/sole_unizon/) on 2020-05-06**:
sorry about that. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I have found the answer!
(Sorry for all the ruckus I made).

My mistakes are:

1. I didn't properly create my package in catkin_ws/src. I put them in catkin_ws and then moved them into catkin_ws/src folder.
2. I didn't put the basic_shapes.cpp in the CORRECT SRC folder. I put them inside catkin_ws/src. The correct one is to put inside catkin_ws/src/using_markers/src.
3. I simply move the files by dragging (cut/paste). When I encountered the error of not finding the basic_shapes.cpp, I just move it inside any folder then redo the catkin_make command. The correct action is to start from fresh with all the components in correct place.

Thanks for everthing!

---

Originally posted by [sole_unizon](https://answers.ros.org/users/54480/sole_unizon/) with karma: 26 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1